# Is it possible to overlay video with alpha channel over the desktop in real time (Windows)?

Tags: video, skype, overlay, alpha-channel

I'm going to run a pen & paper RPG game and one of my players will participate via Skype. To make his appearance more immersive, I would like to cast some sort of futuristic HUD over the video stream, along the lines of what can be seen in the pictures below:

[image: Terminator HUD]

[image: Futuristic camera HUD]

Assuming that I'd create a looping video of the HUD effects with an alpha channel (so that it can be easily put over other video footage), is it possible to put that transparent video over the Skype window or the whole desktop in real time?

Twitch streamers do similar things all the time, composing multiple elements to the single video feed in real time, so I suspect that the tools are out there somewhere.

[image: Twitch stream with HUD]

Comment: There are numerous programs that can broadcast and stream video, but you can't alter the video, Skype is sending out.  Skype does not broadcast your own output video, in such a way, it would be helpful to other participate.

Comment: Okay, is it possible then to do this on the side of the caller? Modify the web camera output before it goes into Skype or somethiing?

Comment: No; Skype communicates directly to the camera.  You could use something other then Skype for the video of you wanted.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your input. Do you know of any video communication software that allows modifying video streams?

Comment: You could use ffmpeg to capture the Skype video being drawn on your desktop and then use overlay filter and stream or locally play the output, but I haven't tried to cap a Skype video feed and so I don't know the latency introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already noticed streaming software.

I recommend you experiment with OBS Studio.  Based on my experience I think you can use OBS to import a window capture from your skype as one layer, and then place a translucent image on top of that as another layer.  The remaining question is "will the skype window capture work even if skype is minimized?"

I know I've sampled cropped subsections of a firefox window running a webgl animation even with the firefox buried under other windows.

You would bury the skype window and use the OBS preview window (with its composited layers) as your video feed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, crudely, would be to use a media player that can become [transparent](http://daumpotplayer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Transparency-of-a-player.jpg), like [Potplayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/), while applying a minimalist skin. So, play the loop on repeat in Potplayer, change transparency and overlay it over the Skype video feed. There will be a tint, and you'll have to keep the HUD elements pretty bright.

Comment: Interesting idea, and simple. Thanks! I suspect it will dim a Skype video quite a lot, since it is not possible to differentiate between background which should be transparent, and HUD elements, which should be opaque. I will give it a try.